# filesystem access on AWS lambda by dependent modules

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

The javascript function I am using in AWS Lambda is dependent on custom modules. The custom module uses synchronous writes to the file system through `fs.writeFileSync(File, "", "utf8")`. However, Lambda throws an error at this line "EROFS: read-only file system, open ......." Is there any specific ways to let the custom module use lambda's /tmp? Are there any other ways to resolve this error apart from changing the module itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other approach than editing the custom module or configuring it(If custom module has configuration option to configure storage path) to save to the file system. It needs to be edited to point to /tmp.